# Gulp watch execute task only once

Tags: javascript, npm, gulp, gulp-watch

I've installed gulp-livereload to reload pages after making changes in .js files.

Here is the code:

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const livereload = require('gulp-livereload');


gulp.task('jsLiveReload', () => {
  gulp
    .src('/home/ksdmwms/Desktop/projs/others/tests/gulp_test/src/js/file.js')
    .pipe(livereload());
});


gulp.task('watchJsTest', function() {
    livereload.listen({
        reloadPage: 'http://localhost/projs/others/tests/gulp_test/src/index.html'
    });
    gulp.watch('/home/ksdmwms/Desktop/projs/others/tests/gulp_test/src/js/file.js', gulp.series('jsLiveReload'));
});
```

So its listening changes on `file.js`.

When i execute i get this:

```
gulp watchJsTest
[14:05:40] Using gulpfile /opt/lampp/htdocs/projs/others/tests/gulp_test/gulpfile.js
[14:05:40] Starting 'watchJsTest'...
[14:05:46] Starting 'jsLiveReload'...
[14:05:46] /home/ksdmwms/Desktop/projs/others/tests/gulp_test/src/js/file.js reloaded.
```

It reloads only when i save the first changes, if i make another changes its not reloading.

How can i solve this?

Note: Im using  *livereload chrome extension* and Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Do you use gulp with node.js? Where is gulp installed (path)?

Comment: Yes i use it globally, gulp is installed in locally on the project (--save dev)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Browser-sync > Gulp-live-reload**

[Browser-Sync](https://browsersync.io/)

```js
const gulp = require('gulp')
const browserSync = require('browser-sync').create()

gulp.task('js', () => {
  return gulp.src([
      'Files1',
      'File2'
    ])
    .pipe(gulp.dest(''))
    .pipe(browserSync.stream())
})

gulp.task('serve', ['sass', 'js'], () => {
  browserSync.init({
    server: './src',
  })

  gulp.watch([
    'src/sass/*.scss',
    'src/js/*.js',
  ], ['sass', 'js'])

  gulp.watch('src/*.html').on('change', browserSync.reload)
})

gulp.task('default', ['serve'])
```

In serve task, gulp.watch

Comment: Just added this to jsLiveReload solved the problem: .pipe(gulp.dest(''));

Answer (score 1):

If gulp is installed in `/home/ksdmwms/Desktop/projs/others/tests/gulp_test`

you could try this:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    livereload = require('gulp-livereload');


gulp.task('jsLiveReload', function() {
  gulp.src('./src/js/**/*.js')
    .pipe(livereload());
  //.pipe(gulp.dest('')); 
});


gulp.task('watchJsTest', function() {
    livereload.listen({
        reloadPage: 'http://localhost/'
    });
    gulp.watch('./src/js/**/*.js', ['jsLiveReload']);
});
```

Tell me if it works :)
Have you already tried [brwosersync](https://browsersync.io/docs/gulp)?

Comment: It didn't worked. No i never tried ... This solved the problem: .pipe(gulp.dest(''));